# Check if record exists in CakePHP3.5

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

The Following Code returns only a error :Record not found in table "users"

```
if($this->Users->get($uid)->isEmpty()) {
            //do something
        }
```

Because the Table is empty, i want to customize this if the table is empty, and call a new page in browser

Answer (score 12):

`Table::get()` will immediately evaluate the query and return an entity, or throw an exception if the record with the given primary key doesn't exist, ie it doesn't return a query, you cannot call `isEmpty()` on the result.

If you are using `Table::get()` you can catch the `RecordNotFoundException`:

```
try {
    $user = $this->Users->get($uid);
    // ...
} catch (\Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException $exeption) {
    // record doesn't exist
}
```

If you wanted to use `isEmpty()`, you'd need to use a regular query:

```
$query = $this->Users->findById($uid);
if ($query->isEmpty()) {
    // record doesn't exist
}
```

If you don't actually need the result, you can use `Table::exists()`:

```
$exists = $this->Users->exists(['id' => $uid]);
if ($exists !== true) {
    // record doesn't exist
}
```

or a `COUNT` query:

```
$count = $this->Users->findById($uid)->count();
if ($count !== 1) {
    // record doesn't exist
}
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Getting a Single Entity by Primary Key](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#getting-a-single-entity-by-primary-key)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Checking if a Query or ResultSet is Empty](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#checking-if-a-query-or-resultset-is-empty)**
- **[API > \Cake\Datasource\RepositoryInterface::exists()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.Datasource.RepositoryInterface.html#_exists)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Returning the Total Count of Records](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#returning-the-total-count-of-records)**