# Check if record exist in Cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to check if a record exists inside a database. But how to handle with the RecordNotFoundException that's trowed before the `if` statement?

```
$Content = $this->Content->get($id);

if (!$Content) {
   // forward to 404
}

// Go further
```

I've also tried to use catch but that's giving the same RecordNotFoundException.

```
try {
    $Content = $this->Content->get($id);
} catch (RecordNotFoundException $exception) {
    // forward to 404
}
```

Comment: Wrong namespace... **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48730987/check-if-record-exists-in-cakephp3-5/48736624**

Comment: @ndm Thats exactly the answer that I needed! thanks!